# The most minimalistic option for Android Push Notification

Tags: android, push-notification

I have tried several guides from different services such as Parse to implement Push Notificaiton in my android app, but couldn't find the best and minimalistic option for my app.

My goal is to simply send push notification message to all users who has my app installed. I don't care about filters.

When using Parse the push notification worked only when my application was open. when it was closed, I got no notification at all.

My question is - What is the minimalistic and simplest service I can use in order to implement push notification for my app, to simply message all users?

Comment: Try pushwoosh... tooks me minutes to implement and send messages to every single one who install the app.

Answer (score 1):

A natural choice would be GCM for Android since it's from Google

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

It comes with a working example.

I can't say it's most simple but then I implemented my pushes accordingly and it works